# Ember serializer customization for alternate url

Tags: python, json, django, rest, ember.js

I am a newbie to ember. So here is what i faced. I got backend RESTAPI written in python/Django. It provides following json response on `/api/works/`

```
[
{
    "id": 17,
    "title": "about us",
    "description": "some project",
    "owner": "admin"
},
{
    "id": 19,
    "title": "test1 profit project",
    "description": "dev null",
    "owner": "test1"
}
]
```

also on detail view E.g:`/api/works/17/`:

```
{
"id": 17,
"title": "about us",
"description": "some project",
"owner": "admin"
}
```

there is also `/api/works/17/tasks/` for listing work tasks

```
[
{
    "id": 2,
    "title": "secondWorkTask",
    "description": "task2 description",
    "due_date": "2016-09-26",
    "assign": 1,
    "project": "about us"
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "title": "some task name",
    "description": "some task description",
    "due_date": "2016-08-27",
    "assign": 2,
    "project": "about us"
}
]
```

on the front-end side i am using ember-cli version2.7.0 + [ember-django-adapter](https://github.com/dustinfarris/ember-django-adapter). I can get /api/works without problem.

*serializer on ember* to get project:

```
export default DRFSerializer.extend({
  normalizeFindAllResponse(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType) {
   payload.data = payload;
   return this._super(...arguments);
 }
});
```

What i want to achieve is on the **ember side** when work detail url on the ember side(`emberexample-app.com/app/17/`) load, it must show all tasks. Currently i can get work detail by this url `/api/works/17/` with above serializer. But how can i get tasks? Please help me to find a way to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The serializer are used to customize the loading and saving (or serialization and deserialization) of data.

To customize the URLs you must use an Adapter,(e.g. [RESTAdapter](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html) is my most used adapter).

That will work in the case you want to create (`urlForCreateRecord`) or update (`urlForUpdateRecord`) tasks but it may not directly work if you just want to convert a `work.get('tasks')` following a `belongsTo` relationship to a `GET http://endpoint/work/<work_id>/tasks`, at least in my case it didn't "just work"ed.

A solution I found that works very well is adding a property `links` as a plain object to the parent objects that contains links to the different child models you want to retrieve as properties.

Something like this:

```
/* app/adapters/work.js */
import DS from 'ember';

export default DS.RESTSerializer({
    normalize (model, hash, prop) {
        hash.links = hash.links || {};
        hash.links.tasks = this.buildURL(model, hash.id) + '/tasks';
        return this._super(model, hash, prop);
    }
});
```

In this example, when Ember try to get a tasks property from a work model, it will make a GET to the URL that `work.links.tasks` contains.

Comment: is it possible to create task in `/api/works/17/tasks/` do i need to update taskserializer for create task also edit both function should exist in serializer right? current task creating is only possible under `/api/works/17/tasks/` but when edit or delete record it's under `/api/tasks/2/`

Comment: If DRFAdapter extends [DS.RESTAdapter](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html) (and [it does](https://github.com/dustinfarris/ember-django-adapter/blob/master/addon/adapters/drf.js#L21)) it's possible to customize the URL for every action individually, take a look at the methods `urlForDeleteRecord` and `urlForUpdateRecord` in DS.RESTAdapter.

Comment: `urlForCreateRecord` takes modelname and snapshot as an arguments, but how can i specify model id? on backend it works like this `/api/works/17/tasks` for create tasks, it takes works id automatically so when creating a record no need to send about work or work id or something like that

Comment: I did following but in snapshot i get null always. Is it related to model thing?

    `import DRFAdapter from './drf';
    export default DRFAdapter.extend({
      urlForCreateRecord(modelName, snapshot) {
        let workId = snapshot.belongsTo('work').id;
        return `/${this.namespace}/api/works/${workId}/tasks/`;
      }
    });`